# How to get the file name in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipselink

I am trying to build a popup Menu in Eclipse. Actually the plugin has a popup Action that shows a new option when you rightclick in a File. I need to know the File name and the project name in which i have rightclicked. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
IStructuredSelection currentSelection = (IStructuredSelection)getContext().getSelection();

if(!currentSelection.isEmpty() && ResourceSelectionUtil.allResourcesAreOfType(currentSelection, IResource.PROJECT | IResource.FOLDER | IResource.FILE)){
    IResource resource = (IResource)currentSelection.getFirstElement();
}
```

Comment: I have tried that code but Eclipse doesnt recognize "getContext()" action. May i need to install new packages in the classic version 4.2 of Juno.

Comment: I think classic version of Juno is having all the plug-ins required for RCP. I believe it depends from where you are calling the getContext() method. I came across this problem when I was extending one of the Action Provider of eclipse. You can refer to fillContextMenu() of NewActionProvider.java

Comment: If you can put your code here, I can look into it and help you.

Comment: The code is exactly the same that eclipse generates when you create a new plugin with a PopUpMenu. The New accion should be launched when the user rightclick the File, and it goes inside the run method. The exactly code is:

  public void run(IAction action) {
  MessageDialog.openInformation(
  shell,
  "Launcher_Plugin",
  "Launch File was executed.");
 }

Answer (score 0):

First, let's create a popup menu for PackageExplorer View.

```
 <plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            categoryId="TestPopupMenu.commands.category"
            id="TestPopupMenu.commands.sampleCommand"
            name="Sample Command">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="testpopupmenu.handlers.SampleHandler"
            commandId="TestPopupMenu.commands.sampleCommand">
      </handler>
   </extension>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
            <command
                  commandId="TestPopupMenu.commands.sampleCommand"
                  id="TestPopupMenu.menus.sampleCommand"
                  mnemonic="S">

                    <visibleWhen>
                           <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
                            <iterate
                                 ifEmpty="false">
                             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                               <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.*" />
                             </adapt>
                            </iterate>
                           </with>
                    </visibleWhen>
            </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Then, add the following code to `execute()` method of your handler, it will print out the absolution path in console:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
//get selection service 
ISelectionService service = window.getSelectionService();
//get selection
IStructuredSelection structured = (IStructuredSelection) service
        .getSelection();
//get selected file
IFile file = (IFile) structured.getFirstElement();
//get the path
IPath path = file.getLocation();

System.out.println(path.toPortableString());
return null;
```

Reference: [Create popup menu in Package Explorer view](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/02/eclipse-rcp-tutorial-add-a-menu-item-to-the-popup-menu-when-right-click-a-file/)